# Dealing with memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, box2d, emscripten

I'm continuously generating and removing circles in my world with [Box2D](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js). However after a while it runs out of memory:

> Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 16777216, (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs.

`world.DestroyBody` is used to remove the circles, and every `b2vec2`, `b2BodyDef` and `b2FixtureDef` that I have created I believe are freed using `Box2D.destroy`. Nonetheless the error still shows up and I have no idea why.

Here's a link to [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ta670sb9/) that I'm working on.

What would be a good way to deal with memory leaks? Are there tools that can detect them similar to Valgrind in C?

Comment: Chrome dev tools actually does that - open that and go to the `Profiles` tab then you can take heap snapshots and compare and run profiles on allocation which will record what your functions do.

Comment: @vlaz The Profiling tool does show memory usage for the real memory, but it doesn't tell me where in my code am I allocating them and not freeing them.